# Simple Javascript / html to alert

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently playing around with javascript and looking for whenever I press a html button that it will read the value of a html drop down menu and create an alert with it.

Drop down :

```
select id="valueDropdown">
  <option value="lessThanFive">below 5</option>
  <option value="betweenSixAndTen">6-10</option>
  <option value="tenPlus">10+</option>
 </select>
```

when a button is pressed (this part is omitted because it works) then it will call this function :

```
 var e = document.getElementById("valueDropdown");
if(e=='lessThanFive'){
alert(e);
}
```

Comment: Use `if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value === 'lessThanFive')`

Comment: This article will explain what you need to do : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656/Using-JavaScript-to-handle-drop-down-list-selectio

Comment: perfect @Tushar thank you

Comment: Welcome, also read the explanation on the answers on the linked question above.